# как написать регулярное выражение для номера

Tags: java

как написать выражение для поиска номера телефона в котором содержаться знаки "-" но не более 2 раз
+5845654-20-20 true
+5845654-20-20-1 false

Comment: Так и пишите - `((не тире)*(тире)){0,2}(не тире)*`.

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:
[`^(\[^-\]*-){0,2}\[^-\]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/lJmTsa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Или так (как java-строка):

```
"[\\+]*\\d+-{0,1}\\d+-{0,1}\\d+"
```

Оригинал:

```
[\+]*\d+-{0,1}\d+-{0,1}\d+
```

Тестировать удобно [тут](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)